# How to create Scene2d Label?

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I am confused on how I am going to create a scene2d label becuase it takes a skin, what do I need a skin for? I only use them on buttons like this:

```
TextureAtlas btnAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("myAtlas"));
Skin skin = new Skin(btnAtlas);
buttonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("btnUP");
```

I'm confused because when I think of a label, I think of font and text not an atlas or skin. I saw some code online and they were using a .json file and not an .atlas file which confuses me more, how do I create a .json file that holds the font that I want to use? what is .json file? Also I'm using Libgdx framework and when I create an atlas file I just use LIbgdx texture packer to put together a group of texturs.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin

Comment: You don't actually need a skin. You could pass in a LabelStyle that references the font you want.

Comment: Skin is just a convenient way to have all your styles for all your UI available from one place. Its especially useful if you have a complex UI with many styles, because you can define the styles easily with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's start from the beginning:

- **Json files**

  The JSON is a text format - an alternative for the XML. It looks like JavaScript's objects notation. JSONes are being used for transmitting data but also for serializing objects - LibGDX has a nice JSON support already.

  JSON is using `{}` and `:` signs and everything is being kept as text. Example:

  ```
  {
      "name" : "Mike",
      "city" : "London"
      "address" : {
          "road" : "Green",
          "number" : "5"
      }
  }
  ```

  It could be parsed to some `Person` class object or being accessed by using some keys (something like `number = person[address][number]` in pseudocode)
- **Font**

  To define a font you will need .fnt file (generated with for example [Hiero](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/tools.html)). Libgdx is using BitmapFonts - rendered fonts with codes (you can think about it as about textureatlases). There are some method to use directly font files like .ttf but generally it is not good idea if you do not have to
- **Skin**

  Skin is an object that defines your Scene2D instances. You can describe by using Skin how your *buttons* will look or what background graphic will *textButton* have. You can create it directly (like you already do - by creating `new Skin()` instance and adding drawables, styles... to it) or by using JSON file that has all these information inside.

  The JSON file is being parsed to Skin and now you can use it. I can recommend [this tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/18/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-3-UI-Skins.aspx) to get know how Skins work but in a nutshell the steps are:

  `1`. to create TextureAtlas (using TexturePacker of course) with all graphics that you Scene2D UI things will use

  `2`. to create proper JSON file with definitions (take a look at the tutorial)

  `3`. to name **.atlas**, **.png** and **.skin** files the same - so you will have something like: skin.atlas, skin.json, skin.png

  **Notice that Skin JSON is not traditional JSON** - it does not have `"` signs so you will have

  ```
  down: round-down, up: round,
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  "down": "round-down", "up": "round",
  ```

  Also `round-down` or `round` are names of your drawables in your atlas

---

When you will have skin JSON you just creating it's instance and then creating Buttons, Label etc by providin skin instance and style name like

```
    Button b = new Button(skin, "registerButton");
```